# Response string JavaScript undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a program written in angularjs. I'm receiving json data from server when online. I'm developing offline mode now..

I have the problem here but i dont know why i cant fix.

I saved json info to localStorage when program to offline get this json string.

service.js - For webservicecall

```
webServiceCallPost: function(data, action) {
            console.log("data    "+JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log("action    "+JSON.stringify(action));
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (navigator.connection.type != "none") {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: appConst.serviceUrl.service + action,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: data,
                    timeout: 2000000,
                    async: true,
                    success: function(response) {
                        localStorage.setItem(data + action, JSON.stringify(response));

                        deferred.resolve();
                    },


      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    if (xhr.status == 0) {
                        window.plugins.toast.showShortBottom($translate.instant("timedOutError"));
                    } else if (xhr.status == 404) {
                        window.plugins.toast.showShortBottom($translate.instant("timedOutError"));
                    } else {
                        window.plugins.toast.showShortBottom($translate.instant("timedOutError"));
                    }
                },
                beforeSend: function() {},
                complete: function() {}
            });

        } else {
            window.plugins.toast.showShortBottom($translate.instant("checkNetWorkConnection"));
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            var response1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem(data + action)));
            return $http.get('').then(function(response) {
                return response1;
            });
        }
    }
```

Controller.js - Retriveing response.

```
Services.webServiceCallPost('', appConst.services.get_menu_card).then(function(response) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    console.log("Response:     " + JSON.stringify(response));

                    if (response[1].response.status == 1) {
                        if (response[0].data.menu.length > 0) {
                            var categoryResponse = [];
                            angular.forEach(response[0].data.menu, function(value, key) {
                                if (value.menu_image_name != '') {
                                               var extraData = {
                                                        imageUrl: appConst.serviceUrl.menu_image_url + value.menu_image_name
                                                    }
                                } 
                                else {
                                    var extraData = {
                                        imageUrl: 'img/screen.png'
                                    };
                                }
                                angular.extend(value, extraData);
                                categoryResponse.push(value);
                            });
                            $rootScope.categories = globalMethods.getDashboardGridView(categoryResponse, 2);
                        }
                        if (response[0].data.addons.length > 0) {
                            $rootScope.totalAddons = [];
                            angular.forEach(response[0].data.addons, function(value, key) {
                                var extraData = {
                                    "finalCost": value.price,
                                    "quantity": 1,
                                    imageUrl: appConst.serviceUrl.addon_image_url + value.addon_image
                                };
                                angular.extend(value, extraData);
                                $rootScope.totalAddons.push(value);


 });
                    }
                    $scope.getSiteSettings();
                }
                $rootScope.dashboardHistoryId = $ionicHistory.currentHistoryId();
            });
```

Console Output : 
When i check from json pretty print its looking same.

Online Response : https://codepaste.net/op0boq

Cached Response : https://codepaste.net/y3bkd6

Problem:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

When i want to get response[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDFYZ.png).response.status ok is getting.
But when i'm offline and i get cachedResponse[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDFYZ.png).response.status its retriving status is undefined. But exactly same data, why ?

[image: Offline else statement.]

Comment: But when i test it. It's receive like my Cached Response in console.

Comment: Check the link. https://i.hizliresim.com/Prg7Qb.jpg  This was a cached response but its saying undefined.

Comment: Try using return `$q.when(response1)` instead of `$http.get('')` as you are offline... and if you are offline that will not complete

Comment: Now its saying https://i.hizliresim.com/bGWvv8.jpg  in Controller.

Comment: Then you might have not returned the right thing... but also you shouldn't be doing  `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem())` it should just be `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem())` localStorage items are already strings, stringifying it is going to mess up what you are trying to do

Comment: You didnt do `return $q.when(response1)`. you just put `$q.when(response1)`

Comment: $q.when(response1) dont working. But i change stringfy its worked thanks !

Comment: Like i said, you didnt have the `return` statement before it

Comment: Okey i did it , now working same. What's difference from http get with $q ?

Comment: http.get() is going to try to do a HTTP request... and since you are trying to make it for an offline mode any http request in offline mode is going to reject because its going to fail so the promise you use wouldn't go through. $q.when takes either a promise or a standard value and makes a new promise out of that

Comment: I see thank you very much. In Addition, i'm using image caching and json save to localstorage for offline working. Is it effective method ? or am i use sqlite database last thing :)

Answer (score 0):

if this code

```
var cachedResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('' + appConst.services.get_menu_card)));
```

uses an asynchronous call

```
console.log("Cached Response:     " + cachedResponse);
```

won't wait for it to finish and would print undefined

Comment: Oh i see when is avaiable. it will write to console isnt it ?
How can i provide to use cached response when offline. I'm using ajax webservice and response return from there. Firstly, i return from this service same result. After i took here.

Comment: localStorage.getItem() might be

Comment: [look at the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) if it was async it would either return a promise or require a callback

Comment: I'm using web service call function here for ajax response : https://codepaste.net/4uiva1

Comment: @OzanManav Update your question to include that, and the code where you actually get the error.

Comment: Its doesnt matter async. I'm calling my webservice firstly and if enter the else statement. Get from localstorage and return response.

Comment: Okey i'm Updated now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer to @PatrickEvans

> Then you might have not returned the right thing... but also you shouldn't be doing JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem()) it should just be JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem()) localStorage items are already strings, stringifying it is going to mess up what you are trying to do

and

> return $q.when(response1);